# Multiprocessing in python requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I am actually trying to make about 6 million requests to website. I have no experience in multiprocessing in python. This is how my program looks like. I have a function get_data as follows:

```
function get_data(x):

S_URL = 'some_url'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
           'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1'
}

form = {
    "name": x
}



response=requests.post(S_URL,headers=headers, data=form)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
table = soup.find_all("table")

for i in table:

    nam_e = i.find("td",string="name")
    num_e = i.find("td",string="number")
    add_e = i.find("td",string="address")
    add1_e = i.find("td",string="address1")
    add2_e = i.find("td",string="address2")
    other_e = i.find("td",string="otherphone")
    city_e = i.find("td",string="city")
    cnic_e = i.find("td",string="cnic")
    date_e = i.find("td",string="date")

    try:
        nam=nam_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        nam=''

    try:
        num=num_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        num=''

    try:
        add=add_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        add=''

    try:
        add1=add1_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        add1=''

    try:
        add2=add2_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        add2=''

    try:
        cn=cnic_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        cn=''
    try:
        other=other_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        other=''

    try:
        dat=date_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        dat=''

    try:
        cit=city_e.find_next_sibling('td').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        cit=''


    return nam,num,add,add1,add2,other,cit,cn,dat
```

Now the I want to make parallel requests and then get the data from this function. What I did for individual requests(not parallel) was:

```
codes = list(range(300,318))+list(range(320,325))+list(range(330,338))+list(range(340,350))
codes = ["{:03d}".format(x) for x in codes]
stuff = '0123456789'
y = ''
final = []
for i in codes:
    for c in itertools.product(stuff, repeat=7):
        pin = y+''.join(c)
        num = i+pin
        final.append(num)
name = []
phone = []
cnic = []
date = []
address = []
address1 = []
address2 = []
city = []
otherphone = []

for i in final:
    print("*"*10)
    print(i)
    if get_data(i)==None:
        print("All empty")
    else:
        nam,num,add,add1,add2,other,cit,cn,dat = get_data(i)
        name.append(nam)
        phone.append(num)
        address.append(add)
        address1.append(add1)
        address2.append(add2)
        otherphone.append(other)
        city.append(cit)
        cnic.append(cn)
        date.append(dat)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name,'Phone':phone,'Address':address,
        'Address1':address1,'Address2':address2,'Other Phone':otherphone,
        'City':city,'CNIC':cnic,'Date':date})
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

I know about multiprocessing so what I could do is something like:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
nam,num,add,add1,add2,other,cit,cn,dat = pool.map(get_data,final)
```

But I am stuck here. I also dont have idea how the size of arrays is going to affect the program here because the size is going to be huge. Kindly help a newbie here. By the way `final` contains bruteforced 7 digit numbers with some code behind.

Comment: I had a good experience with multiprocessing queues https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html the way how you handle the huge memory is that the main thread/process will process the data from the queue as they come and frees the memory once the data is not needed. I did couple of TB of data with this and it worked very well.

Comment: So u mean I could do something like :
`q=Queue()`
 and the add add this queue to the function like : `function get_data(queue):`
and the add the nam,phone,address,.... to queue as : `queue.put([name,phone,address,...])`
and then use like this: `p = Process(target=get_data, args=(q,))
    p.start()`. So I will save the whole row as a single item in queue? Will the queue hold like millions of entries?

Comment: Ok so I will just get the elements of queue and store them in a separate list in order to free the queue. Then I just keep saving those lists after like a hundred thousand entries and then freeing their memory and doing that again. Right?

Comment: yes, that is the idea. Just process them as soon as feasible. Don't store everything in memory. If it means saving them somewhere, then yes, save them.  Also, queue supports "maxsize" so if the child processes get too fast, you can slow them down just by letting them wait on adding next item on the queue. There is for sure a better way how to do this, but this is a simple concept to understand and still reasonable for debugging.

Comment: If you are trying to scrape the whole website try looking at scrapy https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ if you are load testing look at https://k6.io/

Comment: @Dan-Dev Its not about if I want to scrape the whole thing, its about the time that it will take

Comment: you want to make 6 million requests, using python requests each request will block https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing) until it gets a response. You have a limit on the number of processes you can open and each process will use resource. So look at Asynchronous Programming with Twisted https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/core/howto/async.html it will be much faser